# Find number days by condition from another column, R

Tags: r, count, conditional-statements, days

I have one data frame like this:

```
Ptt      Date                      Area        
88734    2016-10-23 05:39:18       BA             
88734    2016-10-23 06:53:13       BA           
88734    2016-11-09 08:32:18       MI            
88734    2016-11-19 06:45:27       MI           
88734    2016-12-20 12:30:43       MI           
88734    2016-12-29 02:45:35       FA             
129041   2017-10-05 04:55:24       BA            
129041   2016-10-23 06:45:30       MI            
129041   2016-11-16 07:10:32       FA            
129041   2016-11-29 03:43:54       FA           
120941   2017-01-02 14:54:39       FA           
...
```

And I wanna count how many days each `Ptt` have at each `area`, but I don't have idea how to do this, someone know how?

What I expected is this:

```
Ptt      Date                      Area        Days
88734    2016-10-23 05:39:18       BA           1  
88734    2016-10-23 06:53:13       BA           1
88734    2016-11-09 08:32:18       MI           1 
88734    2016-11-19 06:45:27       MI           2
88734    2016-12-20 12:30:43       MI           3
88734    2016-12-29 02:45:35       FA           1  
129041   2017-10-05 04:55:24       BA           1 
129041   2016-10-23 06:45:30       MI           1 
129041   2016-11-16 07:10:32       FA           1 
129041   2016-11-29 03:43:54       FA           2
120941   2017-01-02 14:54:39       FA           3
...
```

```
dt = data.table(Ptt= c("88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "88734", "120941", "120941","120941","120941","120941"),
                date = c("2016-10-23 05:39:18",
                         "2016-10-23 06:53:13 ", 
                         "2016-11-09 08:32:18",
                         "2016-11-19 06:45:27",
                         "2016-12-20 12:30:43",
                         "2016-12-29 02:45:35",
                         "2017-10-05 04:55:24",
                         "2016-10-23 06:45:30",
                         "2016-11-16 07:10:32",
                         "2016-11-29 03:43:54",
                         "2017-01-02 14:54:39"),
                Area = c("BA", "BA", "MI", "MI", "MI", "FA", "BA", "MI", "FA", "FA", "FA"))
```

**EDIT**

I didn't explain very well.

So, I want know how many days each `Ptt` have at each `Area`
For example: `88734` have 1 day at `BA`, 3 days at `MI` and 1 day at `FA`, and so on.

I want this:

```
Ptt      Area        Days
88734    BA           1
88734    MI           3 
88734    FA           1  
129041   BA           1 
129041   MI           1 
120941   FA           3
```

Thanks!

Comment: `88734 have 2 days at BA`. Can you explain how you calculate days?

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Comment: I know but I am trying to understand the logic of the calculation which is not clear to me.

Comment: ah, I didnt' calculate, I want that result, I dont know either how to do

Comment: I am not asking you how to do it. I am asking you to explain the logic of calculation for `Days`. Why the first value is 1 , second value is 3 etc?

Comment: because have 1 day registered at `BA` , 3 different at `MI` and 1 at `AA`, at data frame on the post

Comment: `# 3 88734  2016-11-09 08:32:18 MI        1
# 4 88734  2016-11-19 06:45:27 MI        2
# 5 88734  2016-12-20 12:30:43 MI        3` 
three days at `MI`

Comment: Do you need `dt %>% count(Ptt, Area)` ?

Comment: no.. this is the length, for example, I have 3 repeated days for `88734`, like 10/08, 10/08, 10/08, and then 10/15, 10/15 (2 repeated days here), and then 10/17, 10/17, 10/17, 10/17 (4 days repeated here). So, this `88734` have at total 3 days counting, not 9 days.

Comment: I guess you should ask a new question with all these details. I am having difficulty understanding it. My answer gave the output that you had initially posted but maybe that is not what you were looking for.

Comment: i will, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `date` column to `POSIXct` and extract the date from it. For each `Ptt` and `Area` you can assign a unique number for each date.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::ymd_hms(date), 
         date1 = as.Date(date)) %>%
  group_by(Ptt, Area) %>%
  mutate(Days = dense_rank(date1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-date1)

#  Ptt    date                Area   Days
#   <chr>  <dttm>              <chr> <int>
# 1 88734  2016-10-23 05:39:18 BA        1
# 2 88734  2016-10-23 06:53:13 BA        1
# 3 88734  2016-11-09 08:32:18 MI        1
# 4 88734  2016-11-19 06:45:27 MI        2
# 5 88734  2016-12-20 12:30:43 MI        3
# 6 88734  2016-12-29 02:45:35 FA        1
# 7 120941 2017-10-05 04:55:24 BA        1
# 8 120941 2016-10-23 06:45:30 MI        1
# 9 120941 2016-11-16 07:10:32 FA        1
#10 120941 2016-11-29 03:43:54 FA        2
#11 120941 2017-01-02 14:54:39 FA        3
```

---

Since you have `data.table` , you can also do this using `data.table` syntax :

```
library(data.table)

dt[, date := lubridate::ymd_hms(date)]
dt[, date1 := as.Date(date)]
dt[, Days := match(date1, unique(date1)), .(Ptt, Area)]
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah, but how can I find these number of days for each ptt and area? I guess I didnt leave all explained, sorry! Like for example, 88734 had 12 days at BA, 45 at MI and 60 at FA? I tried `dt%>%
  group_by(Ptt, Area, Days) %>% 
  summarise(days.length = length(Days),
            maxi.days = max(Days))`, but didnt work

Comment: @ÉrikaSoaresCoelho But that is not what you showed in your expected output? How `88734` has 12 days at BA ? Do you need `max(date) - min(date)` for each `Ptt` and `Area` ?

Comment: It was an example for `88734`, because my real data have more than 90.000 rows, so I needed to know how many days each `Ptt` have at each `Area`. Like for example as result, `88734` had 12 days at `BA`, 45 at `MI` and 60 at `FA`, and so on, I have at really 32 `Ptt` at my real data frame